# GRE Tunnel in CentOS

Tags: centos, ddos, tunneling, tunnel, gre

How to create a GRE Tunnel in CentOS pointing all connections to server A for the server B?

I have a public server with DDoS protection and need to use this as a firewall to filter acess to the other server.

Example:

users -> server A(DDoS protected) -> server B

All servers have CentOS 6

Comment: Where do these servers exist in relation to each other, i.e. same VLAN, same internal network, or have to traverse the internet to reach each other?

Answer (score 0):

GRE may not be what you are looking for. You may be better served looking at HTTP Reverse Proxying (ProxyPass), SSH forwarding, D-NAT or other techniques.

That said, there is a tutorial on GRE on CentOS Linux at [here](http://centoshowtos.org/network-security/gre-tunnel/).